# How to increase logical volume of a disk in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, disk-volume

`df -h` command returns

```
[root@ip-SERVER_IP ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  5.5G  2.0G  74% /
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
cm_processes     32G     0   32G   0% /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process
```

I have a volume with 500GB of disk space.

Now, I installed some stuff in `/dev/xvda1` and it keeps saying that:

```
The Cloudera Manager Agent's parcel directory is on a filesystem with less than 5.0 GiB of its space free. /opt/cloudera/parcels (free: 1.9 GiB (25.06%), capacity: 7.7 GiB)
```

Similarly:

```
The Cloudera Manager Agent's log directory is on a filesystem with less than 2.0 GiB of its space free. /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent (free: 1.9 GiB (25.06%), capacity: 7.7 GiB)
```

From the memory stats, I see that the Filesystem above stuff is installed in must be:

```
/dev/xvda1
```

I believe it needs to be resized so as to have more disk space but I don't think I need to expand the volume. I have only installed some stuff and started with it.

So I would like to know what exact steps I need to follow to expand the space in this partition and where exactly is my 500 GB?

Comment: Suggest you consider having one disk for OS and one for data, just mount the other separately into your instance. That way if you need more space you can just mount more disks. If you need all your data on one disk then you have to follow the procedure below to expand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot resize EBS on the fly. What you can do is create an AMI from the running machine and spawn off a new machine with 500GB root volume (/dev/sda1).

To create an AMI you can login to console and in the navigation pane, choose **Instances** and select your instance. Choose **Actions**, **Image**, and **Create Image**.

As you are already aware of the process of machine creation, the only difference here would be that you select your own AMI this time and make sure you increase the root volume storage to 500GB. To change the size of the root volume, locate the Root volume in the Type column, and fill in the Size field.

[AWS Documentation on AMI creation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html)

Comment: Steps please? I am new to AWS

Comment: Thanks for your response. Also, how do I increase the root volume storage to 500GB?

Comment: Updated answer. The link had all the info, I had to copy-paste from there to here :)

Comment: Oops, just that I am a newbie and so not confident to touch something that's up and running :) I more question,please bear with me :). I have created a snapshot of the volume in use. Do I need to unmount it or something ?

Comment: Did you create an AMI or a snapshot?

We are trying to create a NEW MACHINE with bigger hard disk and delete the old machine. You create an ami (image) of a running machine and using that image create a new one.

Comment: I created a snapshot so that if anything goes wrong, I will have the option to recreate it. Also, If I spawn off a new machine with 500GB root volume, this new machine will be as it is the existing one and will have everything with it that my existing machine has? What does it exactly mean to create an AMI from the existing machine? Does it use the same volume?If not how would may data be as it is ?

Comment: The data will be retained. AMI is the cloud-equivalent of an installation CD/DVD. If you are new to all this then remember fail often, fail early.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47995/discussion-between-kn330-and-gags).

Comment: Thank you so much. When I create an AMI, it already says: Root /dev/sda1 500Gib. Is that correct and what we want? Also, in that case why exactly was the file system all weird in the original instance I created and did not have 500Gib to it ? Also, how is EBS image different from the volume snapshot? Now I have a volume snapshot and an AMI, what should I do next to replace the old instance with this AMI? This existing instance IP was added to a host to form a cluster. Do we now have a new IP for this AMI? @kn330